# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am trying to use tess4j into my java program.
Here is my code:

```
`import java.io.File; 
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract; 
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException; 

class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(); 
        try { 

            String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("captcha.jpg")); 

            System.out.print(text); 
        } 
        catch (TesseractException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am getting these error messages

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer
        at Test.main(Detection.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Pointer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

My folder looks like this:

Main folder:

1. Detection.java
2. lib -> Here I have the "tess4j-3.4.8.jar" file I got after downloading the tess4j and going into the dist folder
3. `.captcha.jpg`

I am not able to solve this issue. Please help.

I am using visual studio code as my IDE.

Comment: The error means you don't have JNA (Java Native Access) on the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tess4j` has following transitive dependencies:

[image]

You will need to include these in your classpath.

PS: You should use some build tool: maven or gradle

Answer (score 3):

The solution above of YogendraR worked.
You have to add the jar files in the **lib** folder of your tess4J folder in your project struture **Project structure** => **Module** => **Dependencies**.
[The jars files to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP6fm.png)

[Add them here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oss1k.png)